# bootstrap 3 to bootstrap 4 cols no longer horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

im migrating to bootstrap 4 however Ive swapped the boostrap-min.css for my pages from 3 to 4 and my columns are all now vertically aligned as as far as  I can see the columns are correct.

I also used a JS fiddle to test and am able to repliate them all being vertical there too. can anyone point me in the right direction, from how ive read the documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mix-and-match this should work

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/4791/

Comment: Can you not remove the `col-sm-12`? If you can then here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/4829/)

Comment: that seems to do the trick, can you not nest columns anymore?

Comment: Good, I'm glad it worked for you. I think you may need to throw another row underneath the parent column for it to work? I'm sure there is some docs on this..

Comment: Yeah, here you go [DOCS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `col-12` as Bootstrap 4 requires a new `row` for columns to be nested.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#nesting

Answer (score 2):

As **[bootstrap4 grid structure is based on flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)**, so you will need to use `row` and `col` grid carefully. Here is no need to `.col-12` div, just wrap your `.col-2` into a row. Also wrap your `.row` inside the `.container` class

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <h1>TEST</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you don't want to remove `.col-12` div, use another row to wrap the `.col-2` elements which is useless <sup>(Just trying to show you the concept of grid structure).</sup>

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
          <h1>TEST</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud delete frist col-xs-12

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we not nest columns anymore?

Comment: @AlexW Of course you can, take a look at my answer